# How to execute export.module using same file in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have `module.export.process` i want to execute this function when i command node `app.js` it should execute the function, i tried to export it again but that does not work, I am new to nodejs any help will be appreciated.

app.js

```
    // Include blinlib to access blink common utility modules
    var blinklib = require('../blinklib.js');
    var snmp = require("net-snmp");
    var logger = blinklib.logger('actors.snmp');
    var msg = require('./event.js');
    var config = require('./config.json');
    console.log('CONFIG', config);
    var session = snmp.createSession("127.0.0.1", "public");

    module.exports.process = function (msg, config, callback) {
        var informOid = msg.event.body.data[0].oid;
        var varbinds = msg.event.body.data;
        var options = {upTime: 1000};
        logger.info("Processing message: ", msg.event.message);
        varbinds.forEach(function (value) {
            value.type = snmp.ObjectType.OctetString;
        });
        try {
            session.inform(informOid, varbinds, options, function (error) {
                if (error)
                    console.error(error);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            logger.info(e);
        }
    }
module.export = process;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just export the process function to an external module:

process.js

```
//Import dependencies    

function process(msg, config, callback){}

module.exports = process;
```

app.js

```
var process = require('./process.js'); 
//declare msg, config, callback
process(msg, config, callback);
```

Alternatively, don't export anything and execute process as IIFE:

```
(function process(msg, config, callback){})();
```